# Is twillo Client Api allow user to Call from Application to Application instead of native call in iOS?

Tags: ios, iphone, twilio, voip, phone-call

I recently integrated twillo iOS SDK in my iPhone app and it is working fine for native call it means i can make call from app to any verified phone numbers.

But my requirement is app to app call it means there is no native call.

So i would like to know if by using Twillio SDK, is it possible to call from application to application ? Something similar to whatsApp. So there will not be any phone number but both phones must have our apps with Twillio SDK integrated.

Please Help me.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

You absolutely can do app to app calls using the iOS SDK. Let me explain.

Your Twilio Client capability token is created with a TwiML Application, which supplies the URL that Twilio will hit when a call is created to find out what to do with it. Normally, you would pass a phone number as a parameter to your `TCDevice`'s `connect` which would be handed to your app URL when the call connects. This would then be used to produce TwiML to direct the call onto that number, like this:

```
<Response>
  <Dial>
    <Number>{{ to_number }}</Number>
  </Dial>
</Response>
```

To make this work for client to client calls, you can pass another client ID to the URL and on your server, instead of `<Dial>`ing to a `<Number>` you would `<Dial>` to a `<Client>`. Like so:

```
<Response>
  <Dial>
    <Client>{{ client_id }}</Client>
  </Dial>
</Response>
```

You can discover which clients are available by listening for [presence events](https://www.twilio.com/docs/client/ios/TCPresenceEvent) with your `TCDevice` object. You will also have to [handle incoming calls within applications](https://www.twilio.com/docs/quickstart/php/ios-client/incoming-connections).

I recommend following the [Twilio Client iOS Quickstart guide](https://www.twilio.com/docs/quickstart/php/ios-client) all the way through, which will guide you through most of these points, including passing parameters to your application URL and generating the right TwiML to accomplish this (though it doesn't cover presence events).

Let me know if this helps at all.

Comment: Hi philnash thanks for reply.
About cabability token generation which is generated from heroku server right now.You mentioned in answer is same i done till now for phone numbers which makes outgoing call ,but about client to client I m confuse in this and also confuse with twiml.How can I make call to twillo number say incoming call ?

Comment: Do I required to set Twiml by myself ? And I read in quick start doc of iOS to make in/out call  we need to setup 2 client one in simulator n 2nd one is in device and for that I need to login with 2 different account.I m confuse here where to make this setting for client and here client means there is no phone numbers right? Is there any setting in twillo for this.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking any more. Could you perhaps update your question with what you have done so far and then we can work with that to make it work for client to client calls.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure it is possible with Twilio. We have used twilio for the same purpose u mentioned (Call to phone numbers) and was working fine. I think the main purpose of twilio is that. Anyways i'm not sure about it.

May be [VoIP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voice_over_IP) will suit for your functionality. **PortSIP** is a good SDK for voice and video communications between apps.

You can download the **iOS SDK** from here https://www.portsip.com/downloads-center/
It is payable like Twilio only if you want to use it for business.

For more refer [here](http://www.portsip.com/)

Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for reply Alex.I research a lot for this app to app call in twillo but not found any idea yet.Here my requirement is to use twillo but i m not sure that app to app call is possible or not.Do you have any idea about using VoIP in twillo ? It is because i upgraded my twillo account so i must find a way to use twillo.

Answer (score 0):

Twilio support sip now. you must have some setting with your twilio account.

As I know ,you can follow [here](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/api/sending-sip) to set your twilio sip server and implement sip client on your ios client.